# How to show only integer values on yAxis of HighChart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We have a set of a data that contains counts of instances of events. These can only be integers. When we display data that has a high enough yValue the yAxis labels are integers. However, when we zoom in to ranges of data that have under y = 5 we see the tick markers show things like 0.5, 0.75, 1.5, etc. How can we force the yAxis labels to only show integer values?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/uDg9k/) is an example bit of code with some data. As you zoom in to the lower value region of the chart you can see what I mean.
This is the current yAxis setup:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '9px',
      width: '175px'
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  }
},
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Set the `allowDecimals` option in the y axis to false in order to prevent non integer tick marks from being displayed:

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '9px',
            width: '175px'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/sBC9K/

Comment: @wergeld But Rikonator's answer only works for this case. You can see on the following chart: http://jsfiddle.net/R8Hub/1/ It doesn't work because the `tickInterval` is higher than 1. And on the same chart using `allowDecimals` it works. http://jsfiddle.net/R8Hub/2/. So this is the right answer.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann, that is interesting - wouldn't this be a bug in HighStock? Yes, I can see that the `allowDecimals` is a more complete answer but the `minTickInterval` worked as advertised in my case.

Comment: @wergeld It's not a bug, I explained that it happens because the tickinterval for higher values is higher than 1, it doens't prevent numbers higher than 1, just lower.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Actually, I agree. A `minTickInterval` of `1` doesn't mean that the `tickInterval` can't be `2.5` or some other decimal value greater than `1`. Here's where it breaks in your example; http://jsfiddle.net/uDg9k/6/. So, yeah. @Asad's answer is correct.

Comment: Well, I am not setting `tickInterval` at all. And I do not see it being set in the examples @RicardoLohmann mentioned. But, I definitely see this as an issue going forward with our charts where we are setting `tickInterval`. Giving Asad the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This works well if you have a dynamic set of axis values.

Answer (score 0):

Wiht echarts - "4.8.0" you just have to do,

```
options = {
            yAxis: {
              minInterval: 1
            }
          };
```