# How to get only whole numbers on the y-axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts. When I get small numbers in my series the y-axis starts using floating numbers. How can I force it to only use whole numbers regardless of my data?

Note: I do have a minimum set to "4", so even when there is one result to y-axis range will be 0-4.

Comment: can you provide a working example on fiddler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Show Only Integer Values On yAxis Of HighChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238780/how-to-show-only-integer-values-on-yaxis-of-highchart)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Set `allowDecimals: false`, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals).

Comment: I searched the API docs `highstock yaxis whole numbers` and it said string not found but Google gave me this answer instantly. Google + Stackoverflow > API

Comment: and how to restrict to whole numbers when you drag and drop points?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/highcharts/draggable-points/issues/73) question on github.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the `tickInterval`.

Setting `tickInterval` to a whole number should do the trick you require.

```
   yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 5
        }
```

Working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/9Lm5r/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Please apply the yAxis property as min: 0 and tickInterval: 1. which is used to show only the positive area of Y axis.

```
  yAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        min: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please apply the **yAxis** property as `min: 0`. which is used to show only the positive area of Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version "echarts": "^5.3.2",

This solution worked for me by setting min interval to 1:

```
yAxis: {
    minInterval: 1,
 }
```

refer :
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.minInterval